# Is sequence of functions defined by$ f_n(x)=x^n$ on $[0,1)$ uniformly convergent?

Tags: real-analysis

I feel that   $x^n$ goes to zero as $n \to \infty $ in a closed proper subset of $[0,1)$. But I am not sure what happens when $x$ is sufficiently close to $1$

Comment: I have a feeling that this is the most asked question on uniform convergence in the world

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given any $0 < \epsilon < 1, n \in \mathbb{N}$, you can let $x = \epsilon^{1/2n}$. Then $x^n > \epsilon$, so $x^n$ does not converge uniformly to $0$ on $[0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for $x\in[0,1)$, $\lim_{n\to \infty}x^n=0$.  Let us see if the convergence is uniform.

Let $\epsilon = \frac14$.  Then, for $x=1-\frac1n$ we have for all $n\ge 2$

$$\left|f_n(x)\right|=\left|\left(1-\frac1n\right)^n\right|\ge \frac14$$

Therefore, $f_n(x)$ does not converge uniformly to $0$.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  -Mark

Answer (score 0):

It does not converge on $[0,1)$ uniformly as other point out, but it **does** converge uniformly on $[0, 1-\varepsilon]$ for any $\varepsilon > 0$. Vaguely speaking, you can bound the rate of convergence of $x^n$ everywhere else by that of $1 - \varepsilon$.